# hardware diagnosis with debian

Tags: linux, debian, hardware, troubleshooting

I have a i7 8550u SOC thin PC that has started acting up lately.  It runs debian 10 (buster). buster backports kernel 5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64. The SOC is housed in a thin PC aluminium fanless housing.  I bought on AliExpress, so that is the minor caveat.  I've had it for almost 3 years now and have not had issues until about two weeks ago.

The UI freezes often, sometimes, after a few hours of use and at times as soon as i log in.  At times i see rendering issues on the monitor, like streaks but that is a bit of a rarity.  When the UI freezes, at times i am able to F2 to a virtual console and do a clean restart from the command line.  Other times, it is completely unresponsive and needs a hard reset.

what i usually use is plasma environment but i also tried gnome with x11 and wayland without any luck.  I have not being able to pinpoint anything using dmesg but i am not an expert.  I suspect it would have to be a case of the problem finding me rather that me finding the problem :)

How can i pin point the issue?  I initially suspected the RAM, so I installed memtester86+ but that thing is not working at all.  when i boot into any of the memtester options, all i see is the debian flash page (for ever).

I am still not sure if its a software update that caused this issue or if its a hardware problem.  I did some research on diagnostic tools but did not see anything beyond memtester.

It is actually a very decent machine, perfect for development and it has a good 3-4 years of life left in it.  I currently suspect an issue with the onboard graphics.. Intel HD 620.   But that's more of a hunch.

Is there something i can do to pin point the issue?  This is not a system that can accomodate an external graphics card as it has no explansion slots beyond m.2 and im not willing to go so far as to invest in an exotic m.2 display adapter to salvage the situation.

btw, i have windows 10 on dual boot and even that freezes sometime after startup.  this is one of the reasons i dont think this is from a debian software update.  i use backports repo, so i always have that lingering doubt but my issues with windows kinds of lays that theory to rest (i think?)

If i can determine where i stand with the hardware, i will need some tips on how best i can use the processing power without an actualy display.

Comment: Have you checked the Hard Disk? Could be a sign of it having bad sectors.

Comment: Start with checking `dmesg` messages. If you had a Windows partition I'd highly recommend OCCT but you still can install Wine and FurMark under it - it has a stress test for both CPU and GPU. Maybe try to disassemble your device and clean any dust in your fans and check whether they are indeed rotating.

Comment: you've had it for three years - i'd recommend opening it up and using a vacuum cleaner and a small brush (a clean artist's paintbrush is good) to remove all dust, especially from heatsinks and chips.

Comment: I'll try cleaning first.  I've opened it up multiple times, haven't seen to much dust to be frank.  It doesn't have a fan.  Just a aluminium chassis linked to heat sink.

Comment: Check temperatures! Install lm-sensors if you don't have it installed.

Comment: UPDATE: I ran OCCT on windows for 45 mins.  Core temperatures reached 80 and remained stable but my aluminium case got really hot.

Comment: UPDATE: I switched back to debian after the OCCT test and used the machine  for about 2 hrs and it was stable.  Left it running overnight.  In the morning it was frozen on lock screen and thr pc case was unusually hot for a machine on standby.  I need to run some more tests but what I have seen on many occasions is that once the desktop locks itself, it never unlocks and goes into a frozen state.

Comment: UPDATE: i ran lm-sensors.  mostly stays at around 40 deg during idle use.  ive seen it touching 80 deg for a few seconds on heavy use like opening up an IDE or things like that.  always settles down very quickly.  in non graphical mode it is perfectly fine, i can leave it running for ever under load and its still ok.  the problems start in graphical mode which leads to be believe it is the integrated graphics (HD 620) that is causing issues.  wish i had a way of confirming this hypothesis and putting this speculation to rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it was a thermal issue after all.  I removed the processor, cleaned the old thermal paste and applied it freshly, both cpu and gpu and everything is fine now.

Thanks for your suggestions.